# get the name of new directory that created out of tar command

Tags: shell-script, directory, tar

How can I get the name of new directories that were crated out of `tar -xvf` command?

For ex. When I run the command

```
tar -xvf jdk-7u17-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

the contents of this tar extracted in a new dir named 'jdk1.7.0_17' and I want to get this name as output of above command or by using any script.

Comment: I believe [unp](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unp) will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that there is a subdirectory in the tar file, or that there is only one.

I have a special script to extract tar archives that first creates a temporary directory, extracts the file in that directory, and then counts the number of entries in that directory and

1. if it is only one directory/file it moves it up from the temporary directory
2. if there are multiple files/directories, it renames the temporary directory based on the name of .tar file (without extension).

You can do something like that and store the latest name determined in that way in a table for further reference in other scripts.

As @jofel pointed out in a comment. The functionality of my script is available in the [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) set of utilities as well. The archive extraction utility does this a well [dtrx](http://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/).¹

¹ <sub>Unless I missed something neither seem to tell what (single) directory was created.</sub>

Comment: An easier solution is to use [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) which has the described behaviour.

Comment: @jofel yes that could have been easier, if only it had been available when I wrote my script. Do you want to post your comment as an answer? Or should I try and incorporate that link in mine (comments are in my experience less often read than the answers)

Comment: Feel free to incorporate that link.